# Making site using table. Why it doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make this:
[image]
Using table. Why table? I want to make this "panels" resizable (like in Blender, NetBeans etc.) when i change size of one panel, others will fill space.
Unfortunately, this code doesn't work:

```
<table class="shell">
        <td>
            <tr>
                <div class="leftpanel">
                    asfasff</div>
            </tr>
        </td>
        <td>
            <tr class="centerpanel">
                fasfasf
            </tr>
            <tr class="bottompanel">
                asff
            </tr>
        </td>
</table>
```

I suspect, I can't put "tr" inside "td". So how can I do that?

Comment: Boooh. Site with table, shame yourself! http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can achieve this *layout* with a single table. Here is a minimal example of how this could work: http://jsfiddle.net/XA2cy/

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="left-panel" rowspan="2">leftpanel</td>
        <td class="center-panel">centerpanel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="bottom-panel">bottompanel</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**On a side note:** I really don't advice anyone using html tables for layouts. I don't know what you want to build and it might work for you. Maybe you can clarify the purpose of your thing, so we can adjust our answers, if needed.

Comment: Ya sure but according to me it's too much standard to use quotes, you can see the answers and create a poll

Answer (score 5):

> I suspect, I can't put "tr" inside "td".

Precisely.

> So how can I do that?

You could nest another `<table>`:

```
<table class="shell">
    <tr class="leftpanel">
        <td>
            asfasff
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr class="centerpanel">
                    <td>fasfasf</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="bottompanel">
                    <td>asff</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also it's been sometime since designers proclaimed using tables to make HTML layouts as heresy. I am not a specialist in web design but from what I am hearing things like `<div>` are modern nowadays. And with the arrival of HTML5 there are special tags for that.

You may check this article out: http://www.expression-web-tutorial.com/Structural-Semantic-Elements.html

Comment: What, `rowspan` is not in favour these days?

Comment: Actually am amazed you answered this :D

Comment: Yes, rowspan is another alternative. As far as what's modern nowadays I think it would be better not to use tables at all for HTML layouts. But I might be mistaken with this :-)

Comment: Why you put <tr> tag inside <td> ?

Comment: @jigneshkheni, good point. Thanks for noticing that. I have updated my answer.

Comment: yeah this is write structure of table.

Answer (score 3):

**I would go with `DIV` elements  and a bit of jQuery.**
Here I created an example with the resize stuff:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AFuzepE/3/edit)**

**jQuery**:

```
var $L = $('#left'),
    $B = $('#bottom'),
    $C = $('#center'),
    $Lr = $('.resizer', $L),
    $Br = $('.resizer', $B);

$Lr.add($Br).on('mousedown mouseup', function( e ){
  var mD = e.type == 'mousedown';
  this.drag = mD;
  $('.box').css({overflow:mD?'hidden':'auto', userSelect:mD?'none':'auto'});
});

$(document).on('mousemove', function( e ){
  if($Lr[0].drag){
    var x=(e.pageX+2)/window.innerWidth*100, w=100-x;
    $L.css({width:x+'%'});
    $B.add($C).css({left:x+'%', width:w+'%'});
  }
  if($Br[0].drag){
    var y=(e.pageY-2)/window.innerHeight*100, h=100-y;
    $C.css({height:y+'%'});
    $B.css({top:y+'%', height:h+'%'});
  }
});
```

**HTML**:

```
  <div id="left" class="box">
    <div class="resizer"></div>   
    <h2>LEFT</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum  etc.</p>    
  </div>

  <div id="center" class="box">
    <h2>CENTER</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum etc.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="bottom" class="box">
      <div class="resizer"></div>    
      <h2>BOTTOM</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum etc.</p>  
  </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.box{
  position:absolute;    
  overflow:auto;   
}
#left{
  z-index:2;
  background:#eee;
  height:100%;
  width:40%;
}
#center{
  background:#ddd;
  left:40%;
  height:50%;
  width:60%;
}
#bottom{
  background:#ccc;
  left:40%;
  top:50%;
  width:60%;
  height:50%;
}
.resizer{
  background:#cf5;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:absolute;
}
#left .resizer{
  right:0;
  width:5px;
  height:100%;
}
#bottom .resizer{
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use tables for layout.

Tables are for tabular data.

Do the layout with `div` and `css` instead.

Comment: but how to make this divs resizable? It will be much more complicated than using tables

Comment: Use width as a percentage - so where is the complication. Also using tables is not useful for screen readers when used for tables